# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined in jest enzyme tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to make tests using jest with enzyme.

This is my test:

```
import 'jsdom-global/register';
import React from 'react';

import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";

import WorkOutForm from './workOutForm';

const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore({});

let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <WorkOutForm  />
    </Provider>);
});

describe('WorkOutForm', () => {

  it('should start a new workoutForm', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()})
})
```

But I'm receiving:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'tempoGasto' of undefined
>
> ```
>   86 | }
>   87 | 
> > 88 | const mapStateToProps = state => ({tempoGasto: state.workout.tempoGasto, tipoTarefa: state.workout.tipoTarefa, data:
> ```
>
> state.workout.data})
>            |                                                              ^
>         89 | const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
>         90 |     bindActionCreators({ addworkout, searchWorkout, changeTempoGasto, changeHoraTarefaMask, changeDataTarefaMask, 
>   changeTipoTarefa, changeDataTarefa }, dispatch)
>         91 | export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WorkOutForm)

In my component I'm using `export default connect` passing my `mapstateprops` and my actions in `bindActionCreator`.

How i can mount this component?

Tried to import the action changeHoraTarefaMask and make a `wrapper.changeHoraTarefaMask('11:11')` but i get the same error

Comment: const store = mockStore({});
You have to populate your store. It's an empty object right now